# How do i get the length of a class element that is added using addClass in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a settings menu that shows up when the page loads, it has a button that hides it by adding the class "hidedown" and removing "showup" and vice verse when showing it.


i just want to minimize the menu after 2 mins in case someone does not click on the button.


my problem is, when i do this

```
if ($(".hidedown").length > 0 ) {
    //hidedown class is present
} else {
   //hidedown class is not present
}
```

i am always getting "hide class is not present" even when the class "hidedown" is there

```
/* so i have this function */
/* minimize the floating menu after 2mins */
window.setTimeout(function() {

    if ($(".hidedown").length > 0) { /* i don knw why this is not working */
        console.log("the menu should minimize");
        $(".settings_link, .companies").animate({
            left: "-=165"
        }, 700, function() {});
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>').removeClass("hidedowm").addClass("showup");
    } else {
        console.log("class 'hidedown' is not there!");  
        /* i get this even when the class is there */
    }
}, 1000);


/* this will hide the settings/companies menu */
$(document).on("click", ".settings_link.showup", function() {
    $(".settings_link, .companies").animate({
        left: "+=165"
    }, 700, function() {});
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>').removeClass("showup").addClass("hidedowm");
});

/* this will show the settings/companies menu */
$(document).on("click", ".settings_link.hidedowm", function() {
    $(".settings_link, .companies").animate({
        left: "-=165"
    }, 700, function() {});
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>').removeClass("hidedowm").addClass("showup");
});
```

Comment: Typo? `hidedowm` vs `hidedown`. Please check.

Comment: thanks Ivan, man u r as sharp as a razor, that was the issue...